# Situation of HTML mails today - bad idea or accepted?

Tags: html, email

I'm starting up an online business and through php mail() I'll let the customer receive confirmation emails of their order, as well as a payment link. I'd like to be able to put in some eye candy to make it look more professional - an image and perhaps a colored header background - perhaps even display the order as a `<table>`.

Are HTML mails acceptable? Will they reach all of my customers? What are the best practices to assure arrival of the mails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org/) tracks which HTML is supported by which email clients, so technically speaking that's a start. They also have some good information on HTML email in general. The major takeaway may be: be careful with Gmail.

I can't speak to whether HTML emails will please all of your clients. Personally, I request plain text versions if they're available.

Comment: One thing to consider is that Outlook 2010 now uses the Office Style model instead of pure HTML/CSS, and that model does not fully or correctly support pure styling conventions. The outcome is that designing HTML emails 'correctly' will often have less-than-desirable results when viewed in Outlook. The folks who do this for a living (like those involved in the Standards project) are a bit up-in-arms about that and are being quite vocal to MS, but so far no official resolution has surfaced.

Answer (score 3):

take a look a this post, here you have an explanation of best practices and the way to ensure the mail delivering.

http://thinkvitamin.com/design/ensuring-your-html-emails-look-great-and-get-delivered/

Comment: ok, so I don't undestand why did yo mark another answer as correct?

Comment: So I understand it's pretty much ok to use html and css in mails nowadays, as long as I keep it as simple as I can. A few backgrounds, font sizes and colors. It's all about reputation it seems.

Comment: Both answers are very good for me and I'm thankful for both, but Joe did more effort and actually explained what it's about. All you did was post a link.