# table generated using html code gets shrunk to 7 inches in lotus notes 8.5

Tags: html, email, lotus-notes

I am having a trouble where in which the table generated using html code when viewed in lotus notes 8.5 looks nice as per the html width.. but when the forward button is pressed, it gets shrunk to 7 inches..i tried increasing the table width in the html code but that didnt help. Can someone who have tried to create html emails and used lotus notes help me resolve this.

This is related to how lotus notes display html content.

Comment: <html> <head> <style> table.table1{ Cellspacing: 0; Cellpadding: 0; max-width:500pt; min-width:500pt; border: 1px solid black; Border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; } Tr,td{ Border-collapse: collapse; } </style> </head> <body> <table class="table1"> <tr> <td>Sl.no</td> <td>Date</td> <td>Item Name</td> <td>Number of items</td> <td>Delivery date</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>17 Nov 2016</td> <td>Battery</td> <td>11</td> <td>20 Dec 2016</td> </tr></table></body></html>

Comment: Why the [`plsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html email with tables send from plsql package and viewed in lotus notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199510/html-email-with-tables-send-from-plsql-package-and-viewed-in-lotus-notes)

Comment: Hi Richard..i am still having the problem..there is no response in the last question.looking for a solution, if it is a fault in the html code or with the lotus notes..

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In short - (R8) memo editor isn't very good at rendering html. It supports basic formatting, but ignores most of the styling.

In general it is a bad idea to rely on html in emails. [Situation of HTML mails today - bad idea or accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509198/situation-of-html-mails-today-bad-idea-or-accepted)